# React Navigation 5 props.navigation.replace("component"); works the same as navigation.navigate() (Back buttons still shown in header)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to use react-navigation 5 replace functionality, but it does not work as expected.

Let's say there are three components:

1. `set-domain.js`,
2. `auth.js`,
3. `some-func.js`

What I am trying:

in `set-domain.js` I set domain and do:

> `props.navigation.navigate('Auth');` this navigates to `auth.js`:

in `Auth` I login and do:

> `props.navigation.replace('SomeFunc');` this should replace to `some-func.js`

Problem is that it does not replace, but it navigates (I have back button in header left and I can navigate back with back button). **HOWEVER**, if I use replace between `set-domain.js`, `auth.js` also, then it works for all screens.

What I am doing wrong here? It feels, that I do not understand how replace actually works, but I couldn't find more details on this in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're navigating from from `set-domain` to `auth` so your stack is `[set-domain, auth]`.

When you use replace, all you're doing is "replacing" `auth` with `some-func` so the stack becomes `[set-domain, some-func]` which is why the back button still shows up and navigating back will take you to `set-domain`.

If you used navigate instead of replace the stack would become `[set-domain, auth, some-func]`.

Comment: Ok, It makes sense, but how can I replace the whole stack? Thanks!

Comment: If this isnt a nested stack you can use reset:
`navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: 'someFunc' }],
});`

Comment: Thanks! that is actually pretty cool. I even reser route on logout, so user could still navigate between set-domain and auth:
            `props.navigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: 'SetDomain' }, { name: 'Auth' }], });`